# How can I filter ListView data when typing on EditText in android

Tags: android

I have a ListView and a EditText. How can I filter ListView data when typing on EditText ?

My code is given below:

```
 public class ListContacts extends ListActivity {

 ListAdapter lAdapter;
 EditText filterText;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Associate the xml with the activity
setContentView(R.layout.activitylist);


     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    null, null,
     null); 

startManagingCursor(cursor);

// start mappings

     String[] columns = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
int[] names = new int[] { R.id.contact_name };


     lAdapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, columns,
    names);
```

/**
     * to filter contacts
     */

```
filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

      filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {



    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {

    }



});
}
```

}// end of class ListContacts

```
        public class ImageCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

         private Cursor c;
         private Context context;

         public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
    String[] from, int[] to) {
super(context, layout, c, from, to);

this.c = c;
this.context = context;
}


     public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {

        }
```

}// end of class ImageCursorAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       srchBox = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.searchTxt);
String srchName = srchBox.getText().toString();
srchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("TExt changed");
        String srchName = srchBox.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(srchName);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                        + " = 1 AND "
                        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " like " + "'" + srchName + "%'",
                null,
                "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + ") ASC");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        Load(cursor);

  }



       /*
 * for loading after search entered
 */

              public void Load(Cursor cursor) {
    // start mappings
    String[] columns = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] names = new int[] { R.id.contact_name };

    lAdapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, columns,
            names);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bcheck);
    setListAdapter(lAdapter);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This might interest you](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items)

Comment: Thanks for the sample.Here Array Adapter is using to set the lsitview. Here im using ListAdapter...can please give me another solution.

Comment: The link you provided is broken. Do you mind posting it again, i don't have the same problem but your answer was linked from here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711459/sorting-data-in-autocompletetextview]