# sorting data in autocompletetextview

Tags: android

The normal way how AutoCompleteTextView shows suggestions, is that it shows only strings that begin with the text the user entered, but the sort order of the results is undefined. Can I somehow sort them by myself? So that when user enters e.g. "g", I show him results beginning with "g" that are most relevant for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order in which you have added the suggest items in the adapter.

For example, if you are using an array adapter, add the items in the preferred order and the AutoCompleteTextView should be showing suggestions based on the user key strokes and based on the order of availability in the array, the suggestions order would be defined by the Android AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: autocompletetextview is working quite good.the problem is if i have items named bars and saloon bars then if i type s then in the autocompletetextview 1st bars is coming and then saloon bars......but saloon bars should come 1st....